# how to set date picker minimum date with one month back from today

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, datepicker

I am using swift with xcode7.3.1 . I want to set my date picker minimum date must be one month back from today.I am using the following code.I think its not correct way.Could you please help me on this scenario.

```
  let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
  let oneMonthBack = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -30, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
  datePicker.minimumDate = oneMonthBack
```

Comment: Just change unit to month and value to -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this function

```
func previousMonth(sender : AnyObject) {
        let currentCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        dateComponents.month = -1
        let oneMonthBack = currentCalendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])!
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

do like

```
    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
     calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!
     let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    components.calendar = calendar
     components.month = -1 // this is for month
    let minDate: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
     print("minDate: \(minDate)")
     datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
```

you get the output of

[image]