# Swift: Get 30 days before 'Specific Date'

Tags: swift, date, datepicker

I have a problem about showing specific date. Here the case, I have a random date from my API (06/16/2015) that always change. I put it into variable name `toDate` with Date type. I need to get 30 days before the `toDate` for my `fromDate` variable.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781435/how-to-set-date-picker-minimum-date-with-one-month-back-from-today) but it's still not working. Note: I don't have any DatePicker in this controller.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let toDate = `your date object`
let fromDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: toDate)

or, 
// If you want to have exactly 30 days before
let fromDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: toDate)
```

Comment: Its work well. Thanks in Advance. Check in 6 minutes

Comment: I think the `value: -30` is that i need

Answer (score 17):

You can use the following code:

```
let today = Date() //Jun 21, 2017, 7:18 PM
let thirtyDaysBeforeToday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: today)! //May 22, 2017, 7:18 PM
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks in advance, + 1 from me